# How to detect faces in the following image by using cv2 and scikit-mage library only

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

Following code is able to detect face in this image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocuuW.jpg) but not in this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmtxg.jpg)

```
def face_detection(cartoon_image):
    grayscale_image = cv.cvtColor(cartoon_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades+'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
    detected_faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayscale_image)
    for (x, y, w, h) in detected_faces:
        cv.rectangle(cartoon_image,(x, y),(x + w, y + h),(0, 255, 0),2)
    return len(detected_faces)
```

how to update the code (use only `cv2` and `scikit-mage`)?

I am trying to to use the above code to detect face in the image but not able to do so.

Comment: `cv.data` does not exist....